# Visual Studio Code no longer jumps to errors in terminal on control click

Tags: visual-studio-code

Formerly I could just run build commands in the integrated terminal, and then control click on the error results to jump to the associated files. This has stopped working with the recent update.

I do not use tasks.json or 'build', I just run the command directly in the terminal.

What can I do?